# Smoothscrolltoposition not working when Recycler inside nestedscrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview

I am using `LinearLayoutManager` with `RecyclerView` which is inside `NestedScrollView`. Everything is working fine but auto-scroll using `smoothScrollToPosition` is not working.

I tried all solutions in stackoverflow but none worked finally ended up with posting instead of searching. Can anyone face similar issue.

Basically i an having `ViewPager` with collapsing bar . `ViewPager` item is `Fragment` which has layout with `NestedScrollView`. `RecyclerView` is inside `NestedScrollView`. You may point me that i can `RecyclerView` directly instead of `NestedScrollView`. But i have other UI on top of `RecyclerView` so could someone help me two days wasted searching in this.

Below is the code i created for testing this behavior.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="jshkjashdjasjdh" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Comment: add your codes for better results

Comment: @ARUNEdathadan i created sample project to test this issue. Scrolltoposition or smoothScrollToPosition not at all working if i put recyclerview inside nestedscrollview. please have a look at the code.

Comment: did u get a solution?